# Any alternatives to absolute positions used for placing elements over element?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML created for every image I have.

As you can see, both the image and the div with class `votingContainer` are children of `stickySpecificContainer`. `stickySpecificContainer` is inline-block which takes the width and height of it's content which in this case is the image. The `votingContainer` is positioned using position: absolute at the top left corner its parent which in this case is the `stickySpecificContainer`.

Now this works all fine and dandy except that there's default bottom margin for every inline-block like my `stickySpecificContainer` which totally screws with my layout.

```
    <div class="home-container-element">
        <div class="stickySpecificContainer">

            <img class='home-image' src='' alt='Random image'>

            <div class='votingContainer'>
                <a href='#' class='' id=''></a>
                <a href='#' class='' id=''></a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.home-container-element {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.home-image {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.stickySpecificContainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: inline-block;
}
.votingContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a live view or an image with the error. I cant replicate or understand what is breaking your layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set font size to 0 on your home container

```
.home-container-element {
   font-size: 0;
```

and set it back to what you need on your voting container

```
.votingContainer {
   font-size: 12px;
```

That will remove the whitespace in between the blocks.

**Edit:**
After being able to view the page, it turned out the problem was that the home containers need to adjust their width in the reponsive layout. When setting inline-block, the width for the sub-container is not 100% anymore so it needs to be set along with it. In order to remove the bottom margin that comes along with inline-block, the above original answer applies.

Comment: I can show you the how it looks on my website - http://onyx.space/ . Use Admin for username and password since you can only see the upvote/downvote if you're logged in. My end goal is just to properly position the voting div on the top left corner but right now the voting container on specific images straight up leaves the div and I have no clue why is this happening. When I change the stickyContainer display to inline-block; the gap between the images widens for no reason.

Comment: I can see the vote boxes moving out on certain window sizes in Chrome and IE, not Firefox. However, if I set inline-block on stickycontainer, I can see it going where it belongs without any impact on the gap between the image. Except when I change the page zoom, but I guess that's no the issue.

Comment: I'm viewing it on Google Chrome on 1920x1080 monitor. When I set inline-block on stickyContainer, the 10px column-gap between certain elements widens to at least 40-50px for some reason. I've changed the code and it should be live. Do you not see the same?

Comment: Now I got you. Set width: 100%; along with inline-block then.

Comment: Yes that solved column-gap and votingContainer issue but now since the stickyContainer is inline-block, my bottom margin is a couple of pixels bigger. I have set the bottom-margin to be 10px but it seems it is around 14px now.

Comment: Regarding that, my original answer applies. Set font-size to 0 in home container to remove that additional space. I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: But what if the container has a child that contains text? Wouldn't that make the text disappear?

Comment: That's why you need to set it again for the child container. As stated above.

Comment: Oh alright, that cleared up a lot, thanks for the help.